# Ansible Login To Fresh Created Cloud Instance

Tags: ansible

I have created a playbook to create a fresh instance out of a cloud image.

Now can somebody please help me to figure-out how can I login to the instance with the key-pair that was used to create the instance. I don't want to use any user other then root to login.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `hosts` file:

```
[servercategory]
54.85.136.142 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/your-ssh-key.pem ansible_ssh_user=root
```

Comment: What if I create for the instance with a fresh key-pair as well as a fresh ElasticIP address? 
So at first I am checking if my mentioned "Key-pair" does exist or not. If yes then of course I can follow the above solution else how can I proceed? By any chance do we have any tactic to download the key-pair before we make the SSH connection.

Comment: where would you be downloading the keypair *from*? Presumably you created it locally, right? I mean, you can't get a keypair from a server you just created. There are many problems with that.

Comment: I got your point.Used "ansible_ssh_private_key_file" parameter in "add_host" module.